# Does using 'create index concurrently' in postgres, help future rows which will be inserted to be free from locks?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Does the `create index concurrently` works only when the table is created for the first time or does it even work for the records which will be inserted in future?

Answer (score 8):

You are misunderstanding what `concurrently` does: it avoids locking the table for write access **while the index is created**.

Once the index is created, there is no difference between an index created with the `concurrently` option and one without. If new rows get inserted, the index is *updated* with the new values. Inserting new rows, does not "rebuild" the entire index.

Once an index is created, inserting rows into the table does not lock the table at all, regardless of how the index was created. Non-unique indexes always allow concurrent insert to the table.

A `unique` index however will block concurrent inserts for the **same** value(s) - but not for different values.

Comment: Let say today my table has 10 records in production and I add ```create index concurrently on (column_A)```

From tomorrow, millions of records gets inserted to the table and indices will be created on the fly. Isn't it? At that time, concurrently prevents locks during writes (insert/updates). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @sofs1: no it's not. Once the index is created the `concurrently` attribute no longer exists. The index will be **updated**, not "created"  when you insert new rows.

Comment: ```When this option is used, PostgreSQL will build the index without taking any locks that prevent concurrent inserts, updates, or deletes on the table; ``` . @ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html Doesn't it contradict to your answer?

Comment: @sofs1: that refers to the process of _creating_ the index. My comments regarding  locks refer to DML once the index is created.

Comment: still confused. For the new records getting inserted after create index command is used, wouldn't it be a concurrent data insert/update?

Comment: Here's another good piece of documentation which goes through the index creation phases: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/create-index-concurrently . And as a note: "The index is fully ready when the third pass finishes. It’s now being actively maintained by all other backends, following usual HOT rules." - so there's no difference after the indexed is created.